# How to delete commentThread object in YouTube with api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In my youtube channel I want to be able to delete youtube comments. The youtube comments are called the "commentThread" resources in [youtube docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads). As shown in the below screenshot, there is not an option for delete operation in commentThread resource.

[image]

When it comes to the comment's replies which are called "comments" in docs, I can delete them as api is provided for it. I can also delete commentThread objects that are only mine. I can't delete commentThreads that other people wrote to my video. The point is, why can I not delete commentThread objects from api endpoint while I can do it via youtube website? Is there any api for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DalmTo could you please help me with this?